# Flutter Initializing gradle and Resolving dependencies takes a very long time

Tags: flutter

Just got started with flutter but my hello world project has not been emulated on my android device because its still initializing gradle and resolving dependencies.
It has taken an hour but nothing works.my internet connection is fine and fast.Is it supposed to take long the first time or? When i run flutter doctor it says no issues found.i need help

[image: a screen shot]

Comment: You'll need to be more clear. Is it downloading? Compiling? What?

Comment: Compiling..the first time i clicked run

Comment: Fast/slow machine? Lots/little ram? Stuck or still working? This would go quicker if you provided more info without having to pull it out.

Comment: machine is fine i5 8gb ram..its running..shows resolving dependencies in the android studio console.

Comment: Check the event log. Looks like it's stuck; you can also try restarting.

Comment: says 'please configure sdk'-the path is fine i also restarted but same issue

Answer (score 1):

Usually the first time you are running a flutter app, some stuff like gradle Etc need to be downloaded. so if it's taking a long time it might be a result of low speed internet.

I faced it when it was going to download Gradle. So I just went to the following directory and changed the Gradle version:

> Project-name => android => gradle => wrapper => gradle-wrapper.properties

Hope it helps you. good luck :D

EDIT:

I need to mention I had an older version that I used to build my projects with. if you have no version of Gradle you have to let studio download it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Now because of some caches in the system. You should go to `file` on the menu bar and select `Invalidate caches and restart`. Then wait for a while for all dependencies to be resolved. Mine below, took almost 20mins before all dependencies were resolved. [image]

Answer (score 0):

It's downloading your dependencies for the first time. it'll take time if you're doing for the first time. just let it complete or manually download the gradle zip mentioned in the 
gradle-wrapper.properties file .
just copy the URL from there and hit in a browser and download it and place it in the respective folder .
in my case the folder was :

C:\Users\User Name.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-5.6.2-all\9st6wgf78h16so49nn74lgtbb